# win32 deleting message loop object

Tags: c++, winapi, design-patterns

I decide not to use switch-case in the message loop. instead, I wrote abstract message class(`MessageHandler`) so that each message inherits the class and implements what to do.

The problem is it's obscure to find where I should make each message objects and delete them. All the messages should maintain until the program ends.
But in my understanding, the only place I can delete this message objects is inside of the close message itself which is cannot be done.

So should I change the whole design of this or is there a way to do this?

here is the message class.
(Sorry, I couldn't summarize the code enough to reduce them)

```
class MessageHandler
{
private:
    UINT message;
public:
    static vector<MessageHandler*> msgs;
public:
    inline MessageHandler(UINT _message){ setMessage(_message); registerMsg(this); }
    virtual ~MessageHandler() = default;
    virtual void handleMessage() = 0;

    inline void registerMsg(MessageHandler *handlerObj) { msgs.push_back(handlerObj); }
    inline UINT getMessage(){ return message; }
    inline void setMessage(UINT _message){ message = _message; }
};

class WMQUITmsg : public MessageHandler
{
public:
    inline WMQUITmsg() : MessageHandler(WM_QUIT) {}
    ~WMQUITmsg() = default;
    void handleMessage();
};

class WMCLOSEmsg : public MessageHandler
{
public:
    inline WMCLOSEmsg() : MessageHandler(WM_CLOSE) {}
    ~WMCLOSEmsg() = default;
    void handleMessage();
};

class WMDESTROYmsg : public MessageHandler
{
public:
    inline WMDESTROYmsg() : MessageHandler(WM_DESTROY) {}
    ~WMDESTROYmsg() = default;
    void handleMessage();
};
```

this is how I use them

```
class EventHandler
{
public:
    bool runMessageLoop(UINT _message);
};
bool EventHandler::runMessageLoop(UINT _message)
{
    bool foundMsg = false;
    for(auto& it : MessageHandler::msgs)
    {
        if(it->getMessage() == _message)
        {
            foundMsg = true;
            it->handleMessage();
        }
    }
    return foundMsg;
}
```

WinMain will call this function.

```
int ApplicationMain (HINSTANCE hInst,
            HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
            char *cmdParam,
            int cmdShow,
            const char *className)
{
    //싱글톤 객체 생성
    ApplicationManager* AppManager = ApplicationManager::getAppManger();

    WindowClass winClass(WindowProcedure, className, hInst);
    if(winClass.Register())
    {

        WindowMaker win(className, hInst);
        AppManager->setMessages();

        AppManager->setRunLoop();
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

`setMessages` dose this

```
WMQUITmsg *a = new WMQUITmsg();
WMCLOSEmsg *b = new WMCLOSEmsg();
WMDESTROYmsg *c = new WMDESTROYmsg();
```

I believe this will cause memory leak, because the message objects never can be deleted inside of `setMessages` to maintain until program is terminated.

Comment: As a solution to this specific problem (without comment on the design) have you considered making the message handler object `static` local objects instead? E.g. `static WMQUITmsg a;`

Comment: As a comment on your design, you might want to look at e.g. MFC and its design, where it's the *windows* (widgets dialogs, etc.) that handles the messages, not specific "message handling objects".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will refer to that. and yes, static is the easiest way to solve this but I wonder if there are other solution.

Comment: *"I wonder if there are other solution"* - Why yes, of course. Don't use message handling objects. It introduces an unnatural decomposition, that you'll regret ever having invented. Messages need to be handled by specific window instances, and different instances will handle messages differently (a `WM_PAINT` message handler for a combo box will be different from a message handler of a button control, for example).

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't consider the multiple windows since I made this while I'm making a game API that only needs one window. Would it be more reasonable if I never create more than 2 of windows?

Comment: At some point you will create a button control, or an edit control. And at that point your design falls apart. Have a look at MFC's implementation. Try to mimic it, and you'll get a lot of things right, without having to think about it. Add proper C++11 ownership semantics and you'll have a universally applicable framework, that's likely comfortable to use, and safe to use as well.

Comment: @IInspectable Okay, thanks for the comment and advice.